# jQuery remove() within Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get Ajax to remove an element within that same Ajax page.  I make a call to a document via Ajax with the following code, but it doesn't remove the element:

```
<input type="text" value="test" name="someel" class="someelement" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.someelement').remove();
</script>
```

I am using datatype = 'html' and other jquery stuff works, but it only works when I use things like the live function and I don't believe you can use that for removing elements, but I could be wrong.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({        
    url: someurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: postvars,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (html) {
        $('#somediv').html(html);
    }
});
```

EDIT 2:

Example: REMOVED URL

Comment: What do you mean by "Ajax page"? Was the document of this page loaded via Javascript?

Comment: Yes, using the jquery ajax function.

Comment: If you always need to not show the element, maybe CSS is an easier solution? `.someelement { display: none; }` (assuming of course that you can't just avoid including the element in the first place)

Comment: The reason it is included in the first place is for a backup solution if javascript is disabled.  So either way, I need to use something like .hide or .remove.

Comment: In that case, why not just call `$('.someelement').remove();` in your success callback after inserting the HTML?

Comment: Was looking for a solution that left the javascript in the pages it is getting.  The reason for this is that I want the same result whether it is through Ajax or if javascript is disabled.  I have achieved this with the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.html() function strips out the javascript, so it is not outputting and therefore cannot execute even with dataType set to html.  The html variable from the success function returns the full javascript and can be stripped down to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove elements before they are loaded, so wait until the page is ready by using the jquery document ready function.

```
<input type="text" value="test" name="someel" class="someelement" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.someelement').remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I thought document ready doesn't call on Ajax loaded pages? In any case, I have tried this and doesn't work.

Comment: @fanfavorite Oh sorry, I wasnt sure what you meant by AJAX loaded page :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe .detach() or .hide() is the solution ?

Comment: I tried hide, but that didn't work and detach is pretty much the same as remove, but I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you need to do in the success function. There is multiple ways to make a ajax call in jQuery, but something like this:

DELETED. Was not working... it seems remove() only affects to DOM elements.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using the success method as I didn't want to touch the ajax function as it is used across the whole site and this is just 1 page that needs this.  Is there anyway to do this within the ajax loaded page?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax says that 'dataype' html should evaluate <script> elements once they are included in the DOM. So it should work the way you have it. Can you see the <script> elements in the HTML source after the ajax request?

Comment: Try 'datatype' : 'script' to test

Comment: You are "injecting" the new container '#content' into the DOM, replacing the old #content: $('#content').html($(html).find('#content').html());  But the <script> with the remove() function is not inside of that container, so then is not executed. If you don't want to modify the 'success' function of your ajax call, then you must find a way to put the <script> inside #content. This way, will be executed.

Comment: It is instead the content div.  Have another look. You will see it at the bottom.

Comment: Inside the content div I mean, but I am looking in firefox live html and it doesn't show it.  I don't understand why the success function isn't copying it over as it is in the content div grabbed by ajax.

Comment: True, sorry I didn't pay attention. I tested in the console log tha ajax request with `$('#content').html(html);` and works for me (with a little delay).